# "The view polls.views.index didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead." Error in Django

Tags: python, django, anaconda

I am following the tutorial in Django documentation. I did exactly as it has said in the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/).

ValueError at /polls/

When I load on browser "http://localhost:8000/polls/" I get this error:

```
The view polls.views.index didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/polls/
Django Version:     1.10.1
Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:    

The view polls.views.index didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Exception Location:     /home/jack/anaconda2/envs/py3k/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response, line 198
Python Executable:  /home/jack/anaconda2/envs/py3k/bin/python
Python Version:     3.4.5
Python Path:    

['/home/jack/Documents/Django Learning/mysite',
 '/home/jack/anaconda2/envs/py3k/lib/python34.zip',
 '/home/jack/anaconda2/envs/py3k/lib/python3.4',
 '/home/jack/anaconda2/envs/py3k/lib/python3.4/plat-linux',
 '/home/jack/anaconda2/envs/py3k/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/home/jack/anaconda2/envs/py3k/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Sphinx-1.4.1-py3.4.egg',
 '/home/jack/anaconda2/envs/py3k/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-23.0.0-py3.4.egg',
 '/home/jack/anaconda2/envs/py3k/lib/python3.4/site-packages']

Server time:    Thu, 6 Oct 2016 10:32:20 +0000
```

Code Of mysite/polls/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    HttpResponse("Welcome to poll's index!")
# Create your views here.
```

Comment: Please add the code of your view `polls.views.index` to the question.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't add it before. I have added it now. You know what mistake did I make that caused this error? @KlausD.

Answer (score 3):

`HttpResponse("Welcome to poll's index!")`  .should be

```
return HttpResponse("Welcome to poll's index!")
```

You are not returning anything from your view.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!